# wxPython: Video not showing but I can hear the audiio

Tags: python, video, wxpython

I'm trying to make a simple program to keep or remove videos from a folder (and it's subfolder) however while I can hear the video, I can't see it.

```
import os
import wx
import wx.media
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip

class VideoSelector(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Video Selector', size=(800, 600))
        
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.media_ctrl = wx.media.MediaCtrl(self.panel, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)

        self.yes_button = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Yes (Keep)", pos=(10, 540))
        self.no_button = wx.Button(self.panel, label="No (Delete)", pos=(120, 540))
        
        self.video_list = []
        self.current_video_index = 0
        
        self.yes_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.keep_video)
        self.no_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.delete_video)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.quit)
        
        self.Show()
        self.load_videos_in_directory()

    def get_absolute_path(self):
        dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        folder_path = os.path.join(dir_path, 'downloads')

        return folder_path

    def play(self, video_path):
        self.media_ctrl.Stop()
        if self.media_ctrl.Load(video_path):
            self.media_ctrl.Play()
        else:
            print("Media not found")
            self.quit(None)

    def quit(self, event):
        self.media_ctrl.Stop()
        self.Destroy()

    def keep_video(self, event):
        if self.current_video_index < len(self.video_list):
            self.check_video_duration(self.video_list[self.current_video_index])
            self.next_video()
        else:
            wx.MessageBox("No more videos in the directory.", "Info", wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION)

    def delete_video(self, event):
        if self.current_video_index < len(self.video_list):
            os.remove(self.video_list[self.current_video_index])
            self.next_video()
        else:
            wx.MessageBox("No more videos in the directory.", "Info", wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION)

    def next_video(self):
        self.current_video_index += 1
        if self.current_video_index < len(self.video_list):
            video_path = self.video_list[self.current_video_index]
            self.play(video_path)
        else:
            wx.MessageBox("No more videos in the directory.", "Info", wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION)
            self.media_ctrl.Stop()

    def check_video_duration(self, video_path):
        clip = VideoFileClip(video_path)
        duration = clip.duration
        if duration > 120:
            os.remove(video_path)

    def load_videos_in_directory(self):
        directory = self.get_absolute_path()
        self.video_list = self.get_video_list(directory)
        if not self.video_list:
            wx.MessageBox("No video files found in the directory.", "Info", wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION)
        else:
            self.current_video_index = 0
            self.play(self.video_list[self.current_video_index])

    def get_video_list(self, directory):
        video_list = []
        for root, _, files in os.walk(directory):
            for file in files:
                if file.lower().endswith(('.mp4', '.avi', '.mkv', '.mov')):
                    video_list.append(os.path.join(root, file))
        return video_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    Frame = VideoSelector()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You've sort of dumped the buttons down on top of the video, without giving it a size or position, so that's all you see.

It's better to throw in a few sizers to avoid this sort of thing, as they'll sort out the positioning and layout for you.

Really! roughly try something like this. ( you may not need to specify the `backend` or it be the wrong one for your system.)

```
import os
import wx
import wx.media
#from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip

class VideoSelector(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Video Selector', size=(800, 600))

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.media_ctrl = wx.media.MediaCtrl(self, szBackend=wx.media.MEDIABACKEND_GSTREAMER)

        self.yes_button = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Yes (Keep)")
        self.no_button = wx.Button(self.panel, label="No (Delete)")

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(self.media_ctrl, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer2.Add(self.yes_button)
        sizer2.Add(self.no_button)
        self.panel.SetSizer(sizer2)
        sizer.Add(self.panel, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

        self.video_list = []
        self.current_video_index = 0

        self.yes_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.keep_video)
        self.no_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.delete_video)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.quit)
        self.media_ctrl.Bind(wx.media.EVT_MEDIA_LOADED, self.play)

        self.Show()
        self.load_videos_in_directory()

    def get_absolute_path(self):
        dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        folder_path = os.path.join(dir_path, '') #downloads')

        return folder_path

    def load(self, video_path):
        self.media_ctrl.Stop()
        if self.media_ctrl.Load(video_path):
            pass
        else:
            print("Media not found")
            self.quit(None)

    def play(self, event):
        self.media_ctrl.Play()
        self.Refresh()

    def quit(self, event):
        self.media_ctrl.Stop()
        self.Destroy()

    def keep_video(self, event):
        if self.current_video_index < len(self.video_list):
            self.check_video_duration(self.video_list[self.current_video_index])
            self.next_video()
        else:
            wx.MessageBox("No more videos in the directory.", "Info", wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION)

    def delete_video(self, event):
        if self.current_video_index < len(self.video_list):
            os.remove(self.video_list[self.current_video_index])
            self.next_video()
        else:
            wx.MessageBox("No more videos in the directory.", "Info", wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION)

    def next_video(self):
        self.current_video_index += 1
        if self.current_video_index < len(self.video_list):
            video_path = self.video_list[self.current_video_index]
            self.load(video_path)
        else:
            wx.MessageBox("No more videos in the directory.", "Info", wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION)
            self.media_ctrl.Stop()

    def check_video_duration(self, video_path):
        return
        #clip = VideoFileClip(video_path)
        #duration = clip.duration
        #if duration > 120:
        #    os.remove(video_path)

    def load_videos_in_directory(self):
        directory = self.get_absolute_path()
        self.video_list = self.get_video_list(directory)
        if not self.video_list:
            wx.MessageBox("No video files found in the directory.", "Info", wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION)
        else:
            self.current_video_index = 0
            self.load(self.video_list[self.current_video_index])

    def get_video_list(self, directory):
        video_list = []
        for root, _, files in os.walk(directory):
            for file in files:
                if file.lower().endswith(('.mp4', '.avi', '.mkv', '.mov')):
                    video_list.append(os.path.join(root, file))
        return video_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    Frame = VideoSelector()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]